# Is it possible to backfill in bq data tranfer service with s3 as data source?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-transfer

I need to schedule a backfill for my data using bigquery Data Tranfer Service, with s3 as source.

But it doesn't seems to work following the doc from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers#manually_trigger_a_transfer_or_backfill)

I select `run for specific date` and set to july, 2023, although Transfer load date is changed according to the image below, but in the 2nd log it still tranfer files as defult modified date, which is `between 2023-11-18 and 2023-12-07`:
[image]

What I need to do is transfer `files modified before 2023-11-18`, like below:
[image]

Comment: According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dts-introduction) bigquery data transfer service  support back fill but It all depends on the data source,the amount of data you request and the source..etc.Without looking into your project it is difficult to address your issue, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.